# till/until/before

Tags: word-choice

Lately somewhere I heard an announcement on a train stop that sounded a bit wrong. Then I put some different words to fix it but now I feel unsure about all the alterations.

> 1. Please do not cross the yellow line **till** the train stops completely.
> 2. Please do not cross the yellow line **until** the train stops completely.
> 3. Please do not cross the yellow line **before** the train stops completely.

Which are right, which aren't, and why?

To me, only **before** sounds right but I can only say that because of instincts. Would like to know the right way. I tried looking for until-before differences but I couldn't relate any to this specific case.

Comment: One possible source of confusion is the way I have seen _until_ used in InE, as if it meant _as long as_. This led, among other things, to a pretty funny promise from a company to not stop their efforts until the customer is unhappy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them are missing the word 'the', so they're all wrong.

Apart from that, they're all correct.

Just note: 'Till' is a shortening of 'until', so it's only used in informal speech.

Comment: Fixed the the in the question since it wasn't the target. Thanks.

Comment: *Till* is perfectly acceptable in American English, and is found in scholarly papers and broadsheet newspapers as well as in speech, and is to be distinguised from *'til*.